# Is "considered" always followed by "as"?

Tags: subjunctives, complements

I have the following idea:

> 1. The reconstruction of object models is performed using a graph
>      matching approach, which ***is considered a*** corner fixing dilemma.
> 2. The reconstruction of object models is performed using a graph
>      matching approach, which ***is considered as a*** corner fixing
>      dilemma.

Which way is correct?

Answer (score 13):

I think you are confusing two different meanings of *consider*.

1. If you *consider X Y* or *consider X to be Y* (these expressions are equivalent), *consider* means "believe" or "maintain": you hold or express the opinion that X is Y.

   > I consider Sartorius a fool.
2. If you *consider X as Y*, *consider* means "take under consideration" or "discuss": you discuss X as if it were Y, or engage with X in its aspect as Y.

   > Until now we have been analyzing this as a practical problem; let us now consider it as a moral problem.

It is not clear in your examples which you mean; but picking one or the other will pin it down.

Comment: Hello, I see this: https://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/consider-and-consider-as   It says **consider as** equals to **consider**.

Answer (score 1):

"is considered a " is more correct. Your sentence means the following:

"The reconstruction of object models is performed using a graph matching approach. This approach is considered a corner fixing dilemma."

I get the impression that you this is not what you are trying to say. How can an approach be a dilemma?

Comment: thank you. may be you found my problem in another corner.. It is also really nice..as now I am thinking whether my expression is totaly out.. anyway, in the second part of my construction, I wanted to say that "This approach is considered as a corner fixing problem. In this sense, is it wrong? or is dilemma doesn't reflect my idea? then what would be good. thanks.

Answer (score -2):

In University, I was taught that you can never "consider as". You always "consider something to be".

- Correct:

  > I consider my dad to be the greatest man on earth.
- Incorrect:

  > I consider my dad as the greatest man on earth.